# Getting TypeError: replace() missing required argument 'dst' (pos 2) error. How to fix this?

Tags: python, typeerror

So this is my code

```
import os
source = "test.txt"
destination = "/Users/Mac/Desktop/test.txt"

try:
    if os.path.exists(destination):
        print("There is already a file there.")
    else:
        os.replace((source,destination))
        print(source + " was moved.")


except FileNotFoundError:
    print(source + " file was not found!")
```

All i am trying to do is to move a file from its original destination to the desktop.
While running it gives the following error:

```
TypeError: replace() missing required argument 'dst' (pos 2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not very experienced in python. Thanks.

Comment: You have an extra set of parens `os.replace((source,destination))` should be `os.replace(source,destination)` otherwise instead of passing two `str` arguments, you are passing one `tuple` argument that happens to contain two `str`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace  You don't need to pass source and destination in a tuple..

Comment: Thanks , i don't know how come i did not notice that lol.

Comment: If you had made your solution as an answer as an answer instead of a comment i would've definitely marked it as most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `os.replace(source, destination)`, `source` and `destination` should  be two different parameters of `os.replace`. See documents here at [`os.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.html#os.replace).